# jQuery increment number on selector

Tags: jquery

Question edited to add jsfiddle.net link by request. Sorry about that. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/AuQL3/

I've got this function that looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.innertabs2 > div').hide();
    $('.innertabs2 div:first').show();
    $('.innertabs2 ul.inner-tab-nav2 li:first').addClass('active');
    $('.innertabs2 ul.inner-tab-nav2 li a').click(function() {
        $('.innertabs2 ul.inner-tab-nav2 li').removeClass('active');
        $(this).parent().addClass('active');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.innertabs2 > div').hide();
        $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).show();
        //$(currentTab).show();
        return false;
    });
});​
```

Notice specifically the number 2 on the '.innertabs' and '.inner-tab-nav' selectors. What is the proper way to make this function more extendible so that it can be reused multiple times on a page instead of manually creating a new function each time?

Here's a simplified version of the HTML I'm working with:

```
<div class="tabs"><!--begin tab container-->

<ul class="tab-nav">
    <li><a href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<div id="MenuContent"><!-- begin main tab's content-->

        <div class="innertabs2"><!--begin subtab set 1 (need to autoincrement number)-->

            <ul class="inner-tab-nav2">
                <li><a href="#submenu1">Submenu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu2">Submenu 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#submenu3">Submenu 3</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="submenu1"><!--begin tab 1-->                   

                {{CONTENT}}

            </div><!--end tab 1-->

            <div id="submenu2"><!--begin tab 2-->

                {{CONTENT}}

            </div><!--end tab 2-->

            <div id="submenu3"><!--begin tab 3-->

                {{CONTENT}}

            </div><!--end tab 3-->

        </div><!--end subtab set 1-->

</div><!--end main tab's content-->
```

I've tried using .each() to get the desired effect but I think my syntax is way off:

```
$(document).ready(function() {


 $(".tabs > div").each(function(i) {
        $('.innertabs' + i > div ').hide();
            $('.innertabs '+i div:first').show();
        $('.innertabs' + i 'ul.inner-tab-nav' + i li: first ').addClass('
        active ');
        $('.innertabs '+i '
        ul.inner - tab - nav '+i li a').click(function() {
            $('.innertabs' + i 'ul.inner-tab-nav' + i li ').removeClass('
            active ');
            $(this).parent().addClass('
            active ');
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('
            href ');
            $('.innertabs '+i > div').hide();
            $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).show();
            //$(currentTab).show();
            return false;
        }
        });
    });​
```

Comment: Your code would much better looked in for example http://jsfiddle.net and there everyone could run it and see your problem better.

Comment: You're right, was not aware of jsfiddle.net. Here's the link to my actual code and hopefully you can better see what I am trying to accomplish: http://jsfiddle.net/AuQL3/

Answer (score 4):

Instead of doing a needless iteration with `.each()`, you could use the starts-with attribute selector `^=` as follows:

```
$('[class^="innertabs"] > div').hide();
$('[class^="innertabs"] div:first').show();
$('[class^="innertabs"] ul[class^="inner-tab-nav"] li:first').addClass('active');
$('[class^="innertabs"] ul[class^="inner-tab-nav"] li a').click(function() {
    $('[class^="innertabs"] ul[class^="inner-tab-nav"] li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('[class^="innertabs"] > div').hide();
    $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Nice way of doing this. I really need to start looking at the different attribute selectors more.

Comment: But I need my script to look for a number (or some other identifier) on the end of the 'innertabs' selector, not the text 'innertabs' only. Maybe I misunderstand how this is supposed to work?

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a bunch of `+` and `'` and you also have extra `}` at the end

```
$(".tabs > div").each(function(i) {
    $('.innertabs' + i + ' > div ').hide();
    $('.innertabs '+i +' div:first').show();
    $('.innertabs' + i + 'ul.inner-tab-nav' + i + ' li: first ').addClass('active ');
    $('.innertabs '+i +'ul.inner - tab - nav '+i+' li a').click(function() {
    $('.innertabs' + i +' ul.inner-tab-nav' + i +' li ').removeClass('active');
    $(this).parent().addClass('active');
    var currentTab = $(this).attr('href');
    $('.innertabs '+i +' > div').hide();
    $(currentTab).fadeIn(400).show();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: +1 well spot. @Derek This is a very good reason to use some IDE. Personally, NetBeans my favourite. Using an IDE will help you to avoid such issues.

Comment: Yeah I figured my syntax was off. Still couldn't get this code to work, even after I fixed the extra spaces thrown in there.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is use several classes to differenciate the elements while having common classes that you can use in your scripts:

```
<div class="tabs">

    <ul class="tab-nav">

    <div class="inner-tabs second">
        <ul class="inner-tab-nav second">
        </ul>

        <div class="inner-tabs third">
            <ul class="inner-tab-nav third">
            </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

In your script, you can simply use the class `.inner-tabs` to code the behavior.
In your CSS, you can then combine `.inner-tabs.second` for differenciating the styling.

I think this use of CSS classes produces much cleaner markup as well as more semantic.

Besides, using too complex jquery selectors slows down the selections and are less readable: `.inner-tabs` makes more sense at first sight then `[class^="innertabs"]` right ?

Comment: Good point. However, I'm still not sure how to create a function that will iterate over the '.innertab' and '.inner-tab-nav' selectors. How do I specify the 'second' and 'third' selectors in my script?

Comment: Why would you? If the behavior is the same, you don't really care if it is the second or third...